# Resolving warnings when building Azure SDK 2.3 project?

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-sdk-.net

I'm getting 110 warnings in my build after installing Azure SDK 2.3 that I don't recall seeing before. They are all for the file "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets".

An example of one such warning is:
The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element 'CloudToolsVersion'.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or know the right way to fix it?

Comment: I should say everything works, but I don't like having a bunch of msbuild schema validation warnings since it will mask real warnings (and I just don't like having any warnings in the build).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like I just needed to close any open editors for msbuild project files to get those to disappear. Other answers I found suggested on the web were to disable schema validation or to extend the schema myself.

Answer (score 0):

Very scary!  From your solution and hints from other similar questions, I think I know what's going on:  When any build script file (such as a .props) is open in a text editor, it turns on `/validate`.  This is used to see red wavies in the editor and gives the warnings when the project is loaded by any MSBuild task.  The schema holds the various element used by the MS targets infrastructure, and doesn't know anything else.  I'm not sure what good that is, but there you have it.